# How do i create an xml sitemap for my website when the entire site is generated in 1 file, index php

Tags: php, sitemap

So my site has 1 file in it. `index.php`
it generates new pages based on request variables.
For example:
let's say i have 3 categories:

- 1.People
  2.Cars
  3.Food

When site loads `index.php?CategoryID=1`
Page displays people.
... 
and so on.

Any program I've tried it generates a sitemap with 1 page: index.php

My question is this:

```
index.php?CategoryID=1 is one page?
index.php?CategoryID=2 is one page?
index.php?CategoryID=3 is one page?
```

or all 3 are one single page and my site cannot be splited in different pages?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: About which kind of sitemap are you talking about? Do you refer to some standard format here (you write XML sitemap). If so, what does that standards documentation suggest in your case?

Answer (score 0):

Sitemaps are useful when there are many pages and when these pages are not necessarily linked by links. For one page it is not necessary

In other words sitemaps are usefule -

1. When your users cant navigate to where they want to go
2. When you don't know how to link to your best content.

Comment: Well, here's my problem: every page loads different products. Those products could respond as keywords in google search engine. From what i read in google analytic you still need to do sitemaps for dynamic content. Isn't my site an dynamic content?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try http://create-site-map.com ? I had the same scenario with my website and I use them to generate it. You can see my website sitemap here: http://thousandwordscards.com/sitemap.xml